# How to delete Edges and how to delete Document with relationships with Arango and Spring Data integration?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, arangodb

I need to remove a document of ArangoDb through Spring Data integration.
This happens with `relatedRepo.delete (document); .`

It seems that if a Document is deleted the Edges from/to it still remain.
Is it correct?

In this case how can I remove the Edges? 
How can I find an Edge?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data ArangoDB does not perform cascade deletes of related edges. To achieve such behavior you could use the driver directly: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/latest/com/arangodb/ArangoVertexCollection.html#deleteVertex(java.lang.String)